# Given an $F$-module, is the multiplicative identity unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra

This may be a rather basic question, however, embarrassingly I am struggling with it (please note I am new to abstract algebra beyond undergrad group theory). I had as an exercise to show that an $F$-module, say $(F,M)$ is a vector space over a field and vice versa. When showing the converse direction, I used the fact that there exists a multiplicative identity in a vector space over a field. Call it $1'$. Now this implies

$$m = (1')m \Rightarrow (1)m =  (1*1')m = (1')m= m \; \forall m \in M.$$

However, I wanted to show or dream up a counter example that $1' = 1$. My attempt to show $1'=1$ went as follows:

$$(1)m - (1') m = (1'-1)m = 0 \;  \forall m \in M.$$

However, I would need to show then that $fn= 0 \; \forall n \in M \Rightarrow f = 0 \in F$. I could not come up with a proof for this statement.

I tried to come up with some counter examples, however, I failed to find a counterexample that involved a field. For instance, $(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}_2)$ with $\alpha:\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$ via $ \alpha(z,x) = z*x$   could be looked at as an $R$-module which would in fact have several multiplicative identities (the odds). When I tried to extend this idea to fields I failed.

Comment: I'm a little puzzled what this problem is asking to show, i.e., the $R$-module axioms are the same as the vector space axioms, only without the requirement that $R$ be a field. Perhaps I'm unclear on the notation $(F,M)$?

Comment: This is true for fields, assuming that $M$ is not the trivial $F$-module. To see this, note that if $f\ne 0$, we may let $n=f^{-1}m$ where $m$ is any nonzero element, then $fn=m\ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $M$ is a vector space then $1 \cdot m=m$ for all $m \in M$. For extra information, this is not necessarily true about modules. Suppose $R$ is a ring with identity, then we can have an $R$-module or a unitary $R$-module. A unitary $R$-module $A$ is an $R$-module with an extra condition which is $1_R \cdot a=a \ \ \forall a\in A $.

We want to show that $f \cdot m=0 \ \ \forall m \in M$ implies $f=0$. Choose $m \ne 0$. Since $F$ is a field, for every nonzero element of $F$ there exists an inverse element. If $f \ne 0$ then $f^{-1}f\cdot m =1 \cdot m =0$. This is a contradiction since $1 \cdot m =m \ne 0$. Hence $f=0$.

Comment: A note that what you've said in your first paragraph is highly dependent on convention. It's very common convention to use the phrase "$R$-module" to mean "unital $R$-module". For example, the definition of an $R$-module given on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)#Formal_definition) takes rings to be unital, and states $1\cdot m=m$ as an axiom.